# Cordova/Onsen iOS app keyboard bug when focussing on a select drop-down

Tags: ios, cordova, keyboard, onsen-ui

I took a video to better explain this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7QvX-po7Ok

So I have a Cordova 5.2.0 app running on iOS 8.4.1 using both Onsen 1.3.0 and jQuery 2.1.3.

I have a form on the app with text input fields and select drop downs. In the video you see I am focussed on a text field, and when try to touch a select box, the drop-down appears, but then the focus moves back to the text field, even randomly to other text fields sometimes.

I don't have any event listeners hooked up to any of the fields. Any one have any ideas as to how I can't stop this behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Currently experiencing the same issue.. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I experienced this same problem, in my case removing the `min-height` css property on the parent resolved this.

Hope this is useful to someone.